# URL-rewriting fails on server

Tags: .htaccess

I have developed a few PHP scripts on my localhost and wrote a htaccess file to make the urls more user friendly.

On the localhost the htaccess file works as it needs to. The URL:

http://localhost/project-bridgestone/read/8?source=red 
gets mapped correctly and is sent to the file:
`http://localhost/project-bridgestone/read/index.php?request=8?source=red` (double ? is as requested)

for this I used this htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
##jsonoutput.
RewriteBase /read/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/project-bridgestone/read/index.php?request=$1
```

the given example of the url is fairly simple, however, it can also be:

```
http://localhost/project-bridgestone/read/rmv;;2;2018;?source=rmv-repo
```

This url works as well.

Then this morning I uploaded all to the server and was bummed that it didn't work.

I edited the RewriteRule so that it matched the server. But on visiting:

```
192.168.0.123/project-bridgestone/read/rmv;;2;2018;?source=rmv-repo
```

the URL gets rewritten so that my second `?` gets omitted; also the URL in the address bar changes to: `192.168.0.123/project-bridgestone/read/index.php?request=rmv;;2;2018;`

I checked the httpd.conf file, but nothing in there makes me believe that it's affecting the /project-bridgestone/ directory. I tested it by removing the htaccess file and going to:  `192.168.0.123/project-bridgestone/read/index.php?request=rmv;;2;2018;?source=rmv-repo` this worked as on my localhost, with the exception of the way the URL is written.

In the httpd.conf file AllowOverwrite is set to All.

The essence of what the htaccess file should do is take the URL string that comes after /read/ and 'forward' it to ...`/read/index.php?request=<URL_string>` without displaying the long path in the address bar.

How do I go about this?
What causes htaccess files to work on the localhost but fail on the server (I have no configuration rights)? (out of curiosity).

Comment: Don't include the host name in the rewrite rule. Rewrite to `/project-...`, not `http://...`.

Comment: Thanks @deceze, that did it! (I feel like an buffoon now, but I won't make this mistake twice.)